# button background color is always purple in android studio

Tags: java, android, user-interface

I am coding in android studio for some months and everything worked great. In the last 2 weeks I updated android studio and since then, every time I put a button its color is defined as purple no matter what I am doing, even if I change its background.
I tried to change it from the xml and also from the java file but without success.
If someone knows how to change it, it would be very helpful.
Thanks for answers.

[the color of the button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EpJQY.png)

Comment: Change it from the styles.xml

Answer (score 4):

Instead of `button` use `<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton>`

Comment: Please use formatting to highlight code part

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: That worked perfectly for me :)

Answer (score 1):

Setting the `app:backgroundTint` to the color or transparent as well fixed this for me.

Answer (score 0):

Change the theme.xml

```xml
style name="Theme.PROJECTNAME" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

Then the button without background will become grey and can be edited by color and drawable